# React - Map Over Array Of Components To Return

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router

Im trying to dynamically print a lot of components into a `li` list.

In the parent component, the list `menuLinks` is an array. Each child of `menuLinks` is a component (LinkToChangePassword is a react functional component):

```
export default class Header extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super( props );
  }

  render(){
    const menuLinks = [
      LinkToChangePassword,
      LinkToResetPassword,
      LinkToChangeEmail,
      LinkToLogOut
    ];
    return(
      <div className="header">
        <LinkToHome classAttr=""/>
        <h1 className="">{ this.props.heading }</h1>
        <DropDownMenu links = { menuLinks }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my child component, I'd like to attach these components:

```
export default class DropDownMenu extends Component{
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
  }

  render(){
    let renderMenuItems = this.props.links.map(
      ( item, i ) => <li className = "menuItem"
                         key = {`li${i}`}>
                         {item}
                     </li>
    );
    return <ul className = "profileMenu">
            { renderMenuItems }
          </ul>;
  }
}
```

However, this doesnt work & I get empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this once. Maybe this can help.

```
 const menuLinks = [
  <LinkToChangePassword />,
  <LinkToResetPassword />,
  <LinkToChangeEmail />,
  <LinkToLogOut />
];
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1785/

Answer (score 2):

Your trying to reference a react component by name only in JSX *without* surrounding it with angled brackets:

**ComponentNameHere** instead of: **<ComponentNameHere>**

One solution:

You'll need to ensure you are importing you components into you DropDownMenu class.

You can then replace {item} statement within your .map call to use [React.createElement()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

```
{React.createElement(item, null)}
```

Amended render function:

```
render(){
  let renderMenuItems = this.props.links.map( ( item, i ) => 
    <li className = "menuItem" key = {`li${i}`}>
      {React.createElement(item, null)}
   </li>
  ); 
  return <ul className = "profileMenu"> { renderMenuItems } </ul>;
}
```

Comment: They may be made but to use them within JSX you need to call them with angled brackets. I have not found a way to do this dynamically via JSX, but since JSX is just syntactic sugar for methods like React.cresteRlement, using it in your call as I stated above will work